# Python flask web app getting KeyError: '_module' while authenticating google API

Tags: python, google-oauth

I am getting an error on store.get when debugging code below. credential.json is the client secret file downloaded from google cloud console.

```
credential_path = 'credential.json'
store = Storage(credential_path)
print store
credentials = store.get()
if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
    print("Credentials not found.")
    return False
else:
    print("Credentials fetched successfully.")
    return credentials
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace you see.

Comment: I can't see an issue - almost identical to code I have which is no surprise as it's sample code from Google... have you satisfied the pre-requisites? `# pip3 install httplib2
# pip3 install google-api-python-client
# pip3 install oauth2client`